# coredata get element of the array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

I'm using CoreData in my application and I have two entities: `Building` and `Phone` which are connected using one-to-many relation.

I need to set the `number` property from the `Phone` entity to my `textView.text` field in the `table view cell`. 
I use the following code to achieve this (it's simplified for demonstration purposes):

`let a = b.value(forKeyPath: "buildingPhones.number")`

We can see from the output below that `a` variable now hows values of two phone numbers:
`Printing description of a:
▿ Optional<Any>
  ▿ some : 2 elements
    - 0 : +7 7162 40 15 69
    - 1 : +7 7162 25 75 39`

How can I access the first number in this array - `+7 7162 40 15 69`?

P.S. I'm pretty desperate now because I have tried litterely every found method, but still cannot do this. I have tried to access elements like in array, using `object(at: 0)` method and many-many others. Moreover, when I try to cast `a` to any type (`String` or `Array` or `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` it alwats returns `nil`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to downcast the result of `value(forKeyPath` to the actual type `[String]`.

The save way to get the first number is

```
if let a = b.value(forKeyPath: "buildingPhones.number") as? [String],
   let firstNumber = a.first {
   print(firstNumber)
}
```

Be aware that the type of a `one-to-many` relationship is (unordered) `Set`. It's not guaranteed the the order of the array is always the same.

Comment: let c = b.value(forKeyPath: "buildingPhones.number") as? [String] still assign nil to the `a` variable.

Comment: Maybe the key path returns also a set. Please try `as? Set<String>`